# OSX Gradle too old

Tags: android, macos, gradle

Anyways I installed gradle and when I run terminal to compile the app, it says
Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "30ea056c59524902d1004bd520624b7571f1ad77"

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/Test/Desktop/PieMessage/PieMessage-Android/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I would prefer not to use android studio or intellij because they are not letting me run the class for some reason, the RUN option is greyed out, only the RUN.. is available and that leads to debug.

Comment: The error message says "Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'" but you mention that the error is that the plugin is too old. Which one is the error message then? Can you edit the post so we see both error messages?

Comment: It gives both errors on the same paragraph. I didn't mess up any order.

Comment: How are you building from the command-line?  Can you post the gradle task(s) you are executing?

Comment: In one terminal window/screen: cd PieMessage/JavaWebServer && gradle run. This will need to remain open.

In another window/screen: cd PieMessage/PieOSXClient && gradle run. This will need to remain open.

In a final window/screen: cd PieMessage/PieMessage-Android && gradle installDebug. This is simply to compile and load the application.

Comment: Guys correct me if I'm wrong here but it sounds like I need to have the JWS running at all times to receive messages here and the only way to do that is to run Intellij?

https://github.com/bboyairwreck/PieMessage